# How can I use TypeScript in this case?

Tags: typescript, react-native

[image]

I have a Node.js server on my root directory and in the Client directory is a React Native app (expo), both using the TypeScript template. The issue is that the server what every file in the src directory and if I exclude the Client directory in the configuration, the TypeScript form React Native will no longer be working. Is there a way to have two separate TypeScript configs running?
The config from Client directory to watch the Client and the config from foot to watch only the src directory.

Comment: why not use one config per project - its easy to set up a workspace with multiple projects - at least in vscode, not sure if you picture results of some awesome plugin for vim ;)

Comment: Each project needs its own `tsconfig.json` but you can place a `tsconfig.json` containing shared settings in the parent directory and extend it.

Answer (score 0):

`tsconfig.json` files are only applied to their current directory and sub directories (however you can specify it to exclude special directors, in the "exclude" section). It is definitely possible to have different configs for different directories, but your code has to be split across different directories then. Do you need more precise help with any of this?

Comment: yes! if I exclude the clinet dir from in the root config, ts the will no longer be working on client. How can I exclude it but still keep it working?